# mobile website resolution

Tags: mobile, mobile-website, resolution

How are people targetting mobile phones with websites?

I am creating a website that will feature a lot of imagery for Smartphones.  Targetting Android and iOS.

What resolution should I build this website in?  What is the best way to scale it across platforms.  For example, if I build my site at a 640px width and then set the viewport to zoom out for non-retina iphones and android... is there any significant loss there?